# NativeBase Drawer Props

Tags: react-native, native-base

Is it possible to pass props at Sidebar of Drawer (SideBar i'ts my custom component). In this example test props isn't shown in SideBar

```
render () {
 const sideBar = <SideBar onRest={this.changeToRest} test="12" />
    return (
      <Drawer ref={ref => (this.drawer = ref)} content={sideBar}>
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to pass the props to the sidebar custom component

```
<SideBar onRest={this.changeToRest} test="12" />

1.Here you can pass the test="12" as a props 

2.You can get the props at the sidebar component {this.props.test} like that
```

Comment: Yes i do exactly same, but in SideBar {this.props.test} not displaying

Comment: are you using the side bar custom component ?

Comment: No just ```export class SideBar extends Component {```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Sidebar component to the Drawer DrawerNavigator like below

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    MainScreen: {
        screen: TabNav
    },
    ProfileScreen: {
        screen: ProfileNav
    },
    NotificationScreen : {
        screen: NotificationNav

    },
    RewardScreen: {
        screen : RewardNav
    }


},{
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBarNav {...props} test="12"/>
});
```

Comment: And after just change ```<Drawer ref={ref => (this.drawer = ref)} content={sideBar}>``` to ``` <DrawerNav ref={ref => (this.drawer = ref)} >```?